# Onclick of submit button are not displayed values of labels

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have 2 textboxes 1 button and 2 labels, On click of button value of `textbox1` is not displayed at label3 and value of `textbox2` is not displayed at `label2`
I am using `Verify.js` to validate textboxes.
Here is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/jpillora/verifyjs/gh-pages/dist/verify.notify.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" data-validate="required" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" data-validate="required" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text;
  Label2.Text = TextBox2.Text;
}
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: does your code gets hit at all? or can you debug your code if the TextBox1.Text has any value in it?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an OnClientClick property rather than an OnClick property? As shown [on the MS site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user1490835 code inside Button1_Click method is not executed

Comment: may be there is an issue with the verify.js. Try changing your button to <input type="submit" value="submit">

Answer (score 1):

Its is a issue with verify.js
[link](https://github.com/jpillora/verifyjs/issues/22)

Try another to validate like bootstrap [bootstrap validation](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/),form validation [form validation](http://formvalidation.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and i found that it is not hitting server code for some reason caused by verify.js.
so try to set the two labels values using client code.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="test()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
       document.getElementById("<%=Label2.ClientID%>").innerText = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value;
       //Somthing like this
    }
</script>
```

Hope this will help..